# Why are angular ngFor components sharing the same variables

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm making a list of questions (question's name and yes/no checkboxes)

The problem is that when I click on the second question checkboxes, it still changes the ones from first component.

Here's my code:

Rendering the list of questions:

```
<div *ngFor="let question of questions">
  <app-question [question]="question"></app-question>
</div>
```

Each question:

```
<div class="question">
    {{question}}
    <div class="checkboxes">
        <label class="checkbox-label">
            <input class="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checked.yes" (ngModelChange)="checkboxChanged('yes')" type="checkbox" id="check1"/>
            <label for="check1" class="custom-checkbox"></label>
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-label">
            <input class="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checked.no" (ngModelChange)="checkboxChanged('no')" type="checkbox" id="check2"/>
            <label for="check2" class="custom-checkbox"></label>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

checkboxChanged(value): void {
    value === 'yes' ? this.checked["no"] = false : this.checked["yes"] = false;
}
```

Thanks

Edit:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-59bkvw

Solution:
The problem was that my inputs and labels were sharing the same ids between components.
I assigned an unique id like id="{{question}}" and it works. Thank you all for help.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz to replicate the issue?

Comment: I updated the main post, thanks

Comment: Your code is fine. There is an issue with your css. If you remove all the code from `question.component.css` everything works as expected.

Comment: I fixed it by assigning different ids to input and labels, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far I just found you have a single problem related to **label** **for** **attribute** and **input id**. The problem is that the id is not unique, all input elements have the same id. To solve this you have to generate the id dynamically:

Pass the index of the element as prefix of the id :

*template*

```
<div class="question">
    {{question}}
    <div class="checkboxes">
        <label class="checkbox-label">
            <input class="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checked.yes" (ngModelChange)="checkboxChanged('yes')" type="checkbox" [id]="index+'yes'"/>
            <label [for]="index+'yes'" class="custom-checkbox"></label>
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-label">
            <input class="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checked.no" (ngModelChange)="checkboxChanged('no')" type="checkbox" [id]="index+'no'"/>
            <label [for]="index+'no'" class="custom-checkbox"></label>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

*parent component*

```
<div *ngFor="let question of questions;let index = index">
  <app-question [question]="question" [index]="index"></app-question>
</div>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wuhl7n)

Comment: Yes,that was the problem.I fixed it a few minutes ago.I really thought that it's something related to angular and didn't look further in html. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have checked your code and not able to replicate your issue, you need to provide the full code or best would create a stackblitz instance.

Here is the stackblitz instance created by me using the code provided by you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k73iqa

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of questions with Yes/No answers I recommend using radio buttons.

Check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kapxsa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-question%2Fapp-question.component.html) for an example.

```
<div class="question">
    {{question.text}}
    <input type="radio" value="yes" [name]="answer + question.id" [(ngModel)]="question.answer">Yes
    <input type="radio" value="no" [name]="answer + question.id" [(ngModel)]="question.answer">No
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it is indeed a better solution, but I started learning angular yesterday and I would like to know what's wrong in my code. If you want to take a look, I updated the main post with a stackblitz link to my code, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with CSS, not Angular. Once you remove the following CSS from `question.component.css`, it starts working:

```
.checkbox {
    opacity: 0;
}
.checkbox-label{
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I gave every component the same id for input/labels. I fixed it now, thanks